# How do I run rake tasks within my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, thinking-sphinx

What I want to do:

In a model.rb, in after_commit, I want to run rake task ts:reindex

ts:reindex is normally run with a rake ts:index

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you wish this rake code to run during the request cycle then you should avoid running rake via `system` or any of the exec family (including backticks) as this will start a new ruby interpreter and reload the rails environment each time it is called.

Instead you can call the Rake commands directly as follows :-

```
require 'rake'

class SomeModel <ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.run_rake(task_name)
    load File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'lib', 'tasks', 'custom_task.rake')
    Rake::Task[task_name].invoke
  end
end
```

Note: in Rails 4+, you'll use `Rails.root` instead of `RAILS_ROOT`.

And then just use `SomeModel.run_rake("ts:reindex")`

The key parts here are to `require rake` and make sure you load the file containing the task definitions.

Most information obtained from http://railsblogger.blogspot.com/2009/03/in-queue_15.html

Comment: Will this slow down the request? It would be better to put it into a worker right?

Comment: This will almost certainly slow down the request. I make no comment on whether he should do this or not as I don't know his application. I was just helping with the particular question as to "How" he should call rake from within Rails, not whether doing so is  a good idea.

Comment: Did this work for you? I've set it up, don't get any errors, but I don't see the result of the task anywhere, that is the task doesn't seem to be executed.

Comment: Actually I found out you need to use `.execute` instead of `.invoke` for it to work, at least for me.

Comment: Note you may need to call `Rake::Task.clear` followed by `<YourAppModule>::Application.load_tasks `before rake tasks will be loaded in your runtime environment.

Comment: Rather than manually loading the task file, you can simply do `Rails.application.load_tasks`

Answer (score 4):

This code automagically loads the Rake tasks for your Rails application without you even knowing how your application is named :)

```
class MySidekiqTask
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    application_name = Rails.application.class.parent_name
    application = Object.const_get(application_name)
    application::Application.load_tasks
    Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue and couldn't get the accepted answer to work in my controller with a Rails 4 project due to a load file error.  [This post](http://andyatkinson.com/blog/2014/06/23/sharing-rake-tasks-in-gems) gave me a working solution:

```
def restart_search
   require 'rake'
   spec = Gem::Specification.find_by_name 'thinking-sphinx'
   load "#{spec.gem_dir}/lib/thinking_sphinx/tasks.rb"
   Rake::Task["ts:stop"].execute
   Rake::Task["ts:start"].execute
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js { head :ok }
   end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
require 'rake'
RailsApp::Application.load_tasks
class SomeModel <ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.run_rake(task_name)
    load File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'tasks', 'custom_task.rake')
    Rake::Task[task_name].invoke
  end
end
```

And then just use `SomeModel.run_rake("ts:reindex")`.

Answer (score -7):

Have you tried `rake ts:reindex`?