# NameError: uninitialized constant Person::RAILS_ROOT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In 'lib/tasks/admin.rake':

```
require 'rake'
namespace :admin do
  desc "TODO"
  task fake_people: :environment do
    print "How many fake people do you want?"
    Person.all.each do |p|
      print p.first_name + ' ' + p.last_name + '********'
    end
  end
end
```

In `Person.rb(model)`:

```
require 'rake'

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def admin
    load File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'lib', 'tasks', 'admin.rake')
    Rake::Task["admin:fake_people"].invoke
  end 
end
```

How do i call `admin:fake_people` from `call_rake` in model.Please help me i have lost a whole day.

Comment: You can try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675157/how-do-i-run-rake-tasks-within-my-rails-application

Comment: yes i have already tried it but i am getting undefined method `RAILS_ROOT`

Comment: try `Rails.root` instead of `RAILS_ROOT`

Comment: now i am getting `RuntimeError: Don't know how to build task 'environment'
` after using `Rails.root`

Comment: before invoking load the tasks add this line `YourAppName::Application.load_tasks`

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
Rails.root
```

Because probably you have RoR 4. RAILS_ROOT was work fine in RoR 2 or 3.